# Firebase not responding / no callback (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, firebase

When following the firebase examples and docs, nothing is happening on my server, nor on the firebase backend.

When I do dbConf.set({"test","test"}) and then dbConf.once() I get the data. But on the webpage of firebase, nothing is happening to this database.

I run the code below, and bot console.logs stay empty, but as you can see in the screenshot, there is data in the firebase app.

Am I missing something?

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
var _ = require('lodash');

var dbConf = new Firebase('https://blxxxx.firebaseio.com/config');
var dbCred = new Firebase('https://blxxxx.firebaseio.com/printerCredentials');


var config = {};
var printerCredentials = {};

function fillConfig(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());  //NO LOG
    config = _.assign(config,snapshot.val());
};

function fillCredentials(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val()); //NO LOG
    printerCredentials = _.assign(printerCredentials, snapshot.val());
};

function error(err) {
    console.log(err);
}

function save(obj) {
    dbCred.set(obj);
};


dbConf.once('value', fillConfig, error);
dbCred.once('value', fillCredentials, error);
```

[image: firebase screenshot]

Comment: The code above is not calling `dbConf.set({"test","test"})`. Since the behavior depends on where you make that call, please add it.

Comment: This seems to work for me: https://tonicdev.com/puf/stackoverflow33424679. Let me know if I'm doing something differently there or (alternatively) how the output differs from what you expected.